# error in printing char sequence through println in java

Tags: java, arrays, printing, char, println

It should show the output as 3 but it is showing a box(Unrecognized symbol). What can be the problem? It is not a compiler problem, I have checked this in different compilers. Also, the error persists in case of int array also.

```
package basics;

public class Demo3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char a[]={2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println(a[1]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Timothy Truckle By formatting his code you probably fixed his error, just change the char array to int array and it should work as expected. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing symbol #3 from ASCII table and it is "end of text"(https://www.asciitable.com/) If you want to print "3" add single quotes to the digits in your array like this:

```
 char a[]={'2','3','4','5'};
```

Comment: thank you!! it worked :) at the same time I was laughing how can i make such a stupid mistake and couldn't even figure it out all this time. thanks though.